How to get docker-compose back in Fedora 41?
After upgrading Fedora 40 to 41, docker-compose was no longer available.
When I try to re-install with sudo dnf install docker-compose, it raises the following conflicts:
- installed package docker-compose-plugin-2.29.7-1.fc41.x86_64 conflicts with docker-compose-plugin provided by docker-compose-2.29.7-1.fc41.x86_64 from fedora
- package docker-compose-2.29.7-1.fc41.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with docker-compose-plugin provided by docker-compose-plugin-2.29.2-1.fc41.x86_64 from docker-ce-stable
- package docker-compose-2.29.7-1.fc41.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with docker-compose-plugin provided by docker-compose-plugin-2.29.6-1.fc41.x86_64 from docker-ce-stable
- package docker-compose-2.29.7-1.fc41.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with docker-compose-plugin provided by docker-compose-plugin-2.29.7-1.fc41.x86_64 from docker-ce-stable

- installed package docker-compose-plugin-2.29.7-1.fc41.x86_64 conflicts with docker-compose-plugin provided by docker-compose-2.29.7-3.fc41.x86_64 from updates
- package docker-compose-2.29.7-3.fc41.x86_64 from updates conflicts with docker-compose-plugin provided by docker-compose-plugin-2.29.2-1.fc41.x86_64 from docker-ce-stable
- package docker-compose-2.29.7-3.fc41.x86_64 from updates conflicts with docker-compose-plugin provided by docker-compose-plugin-2.29.6-1.fc41.x86_64 from docker-ce-stable
- package docker-compose-2.29.7-3.fc41.x86_64 from updates conflicts with docker-compose-plugin provided by docker-compose-plugin-2.29.7-1.fc41.x86_64 from docker-ce-stable

Running the command line with --allowerasing or --skip-broken does not work either.
I also tried (but to no avail):

removing/re-installing docker-compose-plugin
removing/re-installing Docker as per the documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/fedora)

What more can I try to get docker-compose work again?

Disable the 3rd-party repository docker-ce stable after removing `docker-compose-plugin, then try reinstalling.

@eyoung100 docker-compose-plugin is successfully reinstalled from Fedora 41 Updates but then I am asked to install docker-compose-switch which in turn fails due to conflicts between podman-docker and docker-ce-cli.

Update your question with that output so I'm not guessing at the output.  As a start, I would leave docker-ce-stable disabled, remove both podman-docker and docker-ce-cli. After that I would attempt to install docker-compose-switch which will pull in the required dependencies from Updates.  If you continue to receive conflicts you need to remove every package installed from docker-ce-stable  This is about to have enough meat to turn into an answer.  The idea here is it is ok to remove packages as yu are going to end up reinstalling the packages again.

I discussed the issue on the Red Hat Bugzilla (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2325904). As their answer explains quite well the why and how, I reproduce it here.
Versions of docker-compose

Fedora 40 provides docker-compose v1.x and Fedora 41 provides
docker-compose v2.x. With version 2, the docker-compose team switched
to implementing the compose functionality as a plug-in to docker. In
version 1 docker-compose is a stand-alone application. The
docker-compose team now provides a separate component (see
https://github.com/docker/compose-switch) to emulate the stand-alone
client functionality. This functionality is now available in Fedora 41
(and newer) as docker-compose-switch.

Install from Docker rpms

If you are installing docker using rpms from the Docker community
(e.g. docker-compose-plugin rpm), then the instructions provided at
https://github.com/docker/compose-switch can be followed to regain
docker-compose at the command line with the compose v2 functionality.

Install from Fedora rpms

To implement docker-compose from Fedora rpms, please remove the Docker
rpms such as docker-ce-stable and docker-compose-plugin and then using
'sudo dnf install docker-compose-switch'. This will then include the
docker-compose rpm (as a plugin) and suggest the containerd rpm which
contains docker. Alternatively podman-docker can be installed to
provide a docker alias which will also work with the plug-in.

